# MinGW Interrupt/Exception

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, sfml, codelite

I've setup a project in CodeLite (mingw, windows 10 64bit), that uses SFML with static linking. Rebuilding or cleaning the project produces this output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C E:/DevTools/WinBuilds/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j8 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ SFML-Test - Release-Static ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'E:/Workspaces/CodeLite/SFML/SFML-Test'
codelite-cc E:/DevTools/WinBuilds/bin/g++.exe  -c  "E:/Workspaces/CodeLite/SFML/SFML-Test/main.cpp" -O2 -std=c++11 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DSFML_STATIC  -o ./Release-Static/main.cpp.o -I. -I. -IE:/Lib/cpp/SFML/include
"E:/DevTools/WinBuilds/bin/mingw32-make.exe": Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x00007FFF8AFFEED8)
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 255
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
====1 errors, 0 warnings====
```

If I build the project again it works, until I clean it again.

I've read that this is a problem of make and "(" or ")" in the path. I altered my environment PATH. The path to mingw is the first entry, but the problem still persists ...

Comment: The problem is that `mingw32-make.exe` is crashing. You should see if there's updated version of it that might fix this bug.

Comment: 3.82.90-1-cvs-20120902 is my Version. MinGW Installation Manager's latest version ...